# mysql: set column default values for insert

Tags: import, mysql

I have a sql file from mysqldump a database last month. Now all the tables in the database are added an extra column, say:

```
country varchar(20) not null.
```

how to import the dump file into the database with country set to "US"? The database has data from other countries, so the database can not be deleted and re-created.

Manually I need to do two things to the dump sql file:

```
1. remove all create table statements,
2. add country("US") to all insert statements.
```

But the sql dump file is huge. Is there a good way to achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: The dumped file doesn't contain the column `country`, right? And you want to add `country` column in all the tables having value `US`? Am I right?

Comment: The cleanest way to do this might be set a default value for the `country` column, but this would require that you can issue an `ALTER TABLE` statement, and that the value `US` is desirable for everyone.

Comment: I would find the N tables that are related to this, copy the dump to another file name. Tweak the table names with a find-and-replace-all to new tables names for those N. Note these will be new tables names. Run that script. Now your db has N new tables that are US only. Proceed. Proceed meaning what you meant to do after that (like, do an insert to the other tables? With US as a literal on the insert?)

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD country varchar(20) default "US"

Comment: the database is running behind a web app, and many users are accessing it  in the same time. It involves about 200 tables. Is altering table safe enough?  Is there any programmatic way(tools) to process the dumped sql file? thanks.

Comment: I think alter_table is the best option. Do your operation in the hours with less users and use a log to register queries from the moment of your dump. You can use a script to iterate on all tables and make the update. If you don't have a log of your operation you can use diff under unix to compare the difference between two files, save the difference and make the queries to have an updated DB